# Why did India choose August 15th as its Independence Day?

Tags: india, independence, pakistan

India, Pakistan and Bangladesh were independent from the British rule on August 15th, 1947. Why is it that India celebrates the nation's Independence Day on August 15th  while Pakistan celebrates it on August 14th?

Comment: There was no Bangladesh. Just India and Pakistan got independence from British rule

Comment: "... were liberated from the British rule before August 15th" is a slightly ambiguous phrasing.  Perhaps "... became independent of Britain from the start of August 15th" might be clearer

Answer (score 9):

The [15th of August](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(India)#Immediate_background) was the date chosen by Mountbatten to transfer power, as it was the anniversary of Japan's surrender in World War II.

The act of UK parliament giving independence to India and Pakistan took effect from the 15th of August. The act took effect at midnight, and [14th of August 1947](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(Pakistan)#Independence) coincided with 27th day of Ramadan *(considered sacred night for Muslims)*, which is why Pakistan choose that date instead.

Comment: You Wikipedia link does not say that August 14th was chosen because of Ramadan: "[Mountbatten] chose 14 August as the date of the ceremony of power transfer to Pakistan because he wanted to attend the ceremonies in both India and Pakistan."

Comment: The first commemorative postage stamps of the country, released in July 1948, also gave 15 August 1947 as the independence day,[20] however in subsequent years 14 August was adopted as the independence day.[21] The night of 14–15 August 1947 coincided with 27 Ramadan 1366 of the Islamic calendar, which Muslims regard as a sacred night.

Comment: I skipped the (considered sacred night for Muslims) edit because I was not sure if it was part of the point HorusKol is making here.

Comment: @HorusKol "The act took effect at midnight" - in what timezone?  This is rather relevant here. And what timezones were in effect in Greater India then? (IST has been introduced only after the independence, though it seems this used to be the timezone of British Pakistan as well).

Comment: @RadovanGarabík +1 British India (including Pakistan) was on +5:30 in 1947.  (West) Pakistan is on GMT+5 so 00:00 in what is now India is 23:30 the previous day in Pakistan, providing a rationalisation for the difference